# How to launch the same linux process with different arguments in multiple threads with Poco process

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, scope, poco-libraries

When trying to launch the same C++ Linux program, with different arguments and with `Poco::process`, I get exit 72 code from my second DummyProcess.
This code snippet below is executed in a thread function, which launches every other time, with different task and duration arguments.

When task-1 is running and task-2 wants to launch, its PID gets assigned (different then task1 pid) and tries to launch. At first, `Poco::Process::tryWait()` returns -1 (which means running), but shortly after it returns 72 and program doesn't actually launch.

```
command="/DummyProcess";
args{"task","duration"};
Poco::ProcessHandle ph = Poco::Process::launch(command, args));
rc = ph.id();
```

Everything works fine when executing this snippet in main, not in a thread function, and launching the same program but using two ProcessHandle objects.

Also, everything works fine when processes don't have to work synchronously.
More specifically: if task-1 launches in a thread and it finishes before task-2 launch, then task-2 launches and operates as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer. I ignorantly didn't mention that i was running Linux in virtual box on windows host and was using a shared folder..

I noticed that when launching an executable it's permissions change to -rw-rw-rw from -rwx-rwx-rwx, and i couldn't change them with chmod. So i noticed something fishy here and moved my DummyProcess executable outside of shared folder and everything works like a charm now.